# Entity Virtual Fields works differently in different views - CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 3 tables in database:

- Products: id | title
- Recipes:  id | title | input_price
- Dishes:   id | product_id | recipe_id | quantity

A product includes many recipes with corresponding quantities like:

- Product: Fried rice
- Dishes: Rice | $10 per kg | 0.1 kg
  + Egg  | $1 per piece | 1 piece

```
// in src/Model/Table/ProductsTable.php
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    $this->belongsToMany('Recipes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'recipe_id',
        'joinTable' => 'Dishes',
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Dishes');
}

// in src/Model/Table/RecipesTable.php
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    $this->belongsToMany('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'product_id',
        'through' => 'Dishes',
    ]);        
    $this->hasMany('Dishes');
}

// in src/Model/Table/DishsTable.php
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Recipes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
}
```

I created a virtual field to calculate total cost of all recipes of a single product:

```
// in src/Model/Entity/Product.php
class Product extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'title' => true,
        'unit' => true,
        'price' => true,
        'dishes' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
    ];

    protected function _getTotalCost()
    {
        $dishes = $this->dishes;
        $total_cost = 0;

        foreach ($dishes as $dish) {                // <--- this is line 44
            $input_price = $dish->recipe->input_price;
            $quantity = $dish->quantity;
            $amount = $input_price * $quantity;
            $total_cost += $amount;
        }
        return $total_cost;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly in templates/Products/view.php:

```
echo $product->total_cost;
// result $2;
```

But in templates/Products/index.php it displays an error:

```
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Model\Entity\Product.php, line 44]
Code Context
App\Model\Entity\Product::_getTotalCost() - APP/Model\Entity\Product.php, line 44
Cake\ORM\Entity::get() - CORE\src\Datasource\EntityTrait.php, line 289
Cake\ORM\Entity::__get() - CORE\src\Datasource\EntityTrait.php, line 129
include - ROOT\templates\Products\index.php, line 30
Cake\View\View::_evaluate() - CORE\src\View\View.php, line 1176
Cake\View\View::_render() - CORE\src\View\View.php, line 1134
Cake\View\View::render() - CORE\src\View\View.php, line 764
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 696
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 538
Cake\Controller\ControllerFactory::invoke() - CORE\src\Controller\ControllerFactory.php, line 79
Cake\Http\BaseApplication::handle() - CORE\src\Http\BaseApplication.php, line 251
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 77
Authentication\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware::process() - ROOT\vendor\cakephp\authentication\src\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware.php, line 124
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 73
Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware::process() - CORE\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php, line 156
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 73
```

Please show me how to fix this. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller for your `view` action is likely using `contain` to include the Dishes and Recipes for the Product, while the `index` action is not. You should be able to simply update the `contain` part of the query in `index`, or add it if it's missing entirely.

Comment: I updated in `index` action: `$product = $this->Products->find('list', [ 'contain' => [ 'Dishes.Recipes', ],  ]); ` but it is not working.

Comment: A `list` is just a flat array of (by default) ID and name, it's not entities at all. Change it to `all`, and you should get the data you need in the view. Note that your view probably has something like `foreach ($product as $id => $name)`, and that will need to change to account for the fact that it's entities now.